# Cant setup local ember.js server. Error on "ember server" command

Tags: ember-cli

Moved from github. original thread https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13055

I'm just starting out with ember and I've run in to a problem when using the 'ember server' command.

I ran

```
npm install -g ember-cli
npm install -g phantomjs
npm new test1
cd test1
ember server
```

and get the following error message:

```
version: 2.4.1
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
File: modules/ember-ajax/errors.js
The Broccoli Plugin: [Babel] failed with:
ReferenceError: [BABEL] modules/ember-ajax/errors.js: Unknown option:          /Users/Rubbelogbit/.babelrc.presets
at Logger.error (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:58:11)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:126:29)
at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:107:10)
at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:168:35)
at OptionManager.init (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229:12)
at File.initOptions (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:147:75)
at new File (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:137:22)
at Pipeline.transform (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
at Babel.transform (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:94:21)
at Babel.processString (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:123:25)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
at Babel.Plugin (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
at Babel.Filter [as constructor] (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/index.js:38:10)
at new Babel (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:34:10)
at Babel (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:29:12)
at Object.registry.add.toTree (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/index.js:21:52)
at /Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:184:26
at Array.forEach (native)
at processPlugins (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:182:11)
at Function.module.exports.preprocessJs (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:175:10)
at Class.Addon.preprocessJs (/Users/Rubbelogbit/Desktop/myWebsites/test1/node_modules/ember-      cli/lib/models/addon.js:682:23)
```

And honestly, i have no idea what to do to fix it. I have been googling the problem for a few hours with now luck.

also i literally can't find Users/Rubbelogbit/.babelrc.presets.

Can somebody explain the error message for me or maybe come up with a fix?
Any suggestions and ideas are welcomed, i'd really like to get ember set up  properly so i can use it.

Comment: I also got a similar error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have a global Babel config that's causing incompatibility issues with `broccoli-babel-transpiler`, which Ember depends on.

First, confirm the file actually exists by typing `ls ~/.babelrc`

Which should return `/Users/Rubbelogbit/.babelrc`

Then type `rm ~/.babelrc` to delete the file.

You only need the `.babelrc` file for `babel-core@6.x` and up. However, the broccoli transpiler is still using `^5.0`. I'm guessing because it was in your home directory, it was attempting to use it by default.

Comment: Hi Dalton!
I've had a break from my ember testing, but i got back to it today, and your solution worked perfectly, i cant upvote your answer because of my low reputation but i'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! You'll get better at catching little things like that as you play with JS frameworks more often. Feel free to mark my answer as the **accepted answer**. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for info on how to do this :)